# How can I find the numerical value of the limit of more complex expressions?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Sometimes when trying to find the limit of a function $f(n)$ when $n\to\infty$ using `Limit[f,n->Infinity]`, it seems that Mathematica is unable to compute it numerically. Instead, I get a result like

```
Limit[f,n->Infinity]
```

in place of a numerical value. I'm guessing it is unable to simplify the expression enough to be able to compute a value. In this case it would be helpful at least to know if the limit *exists*, but I haven't found a way to determine this after reading the Mathematica documentation.

My questions are:

> If Mathematica returns the original expression when using `Limit[]`, does this mean it is unable to compute the limit, or am I missing something?
>
> How may I determine the *existence* of a limit in Mathematica, when it is not possible to determine a value for it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mathematica is not always able to calculate limits and sometimes not only gives up, but makes mistakes.

For example, writing:

```
Limit[n Sin[2 Pi E n!], n -> Infinity]
```

we get:

> Indeterminate

when, in reality, the limit exists and is valid `2 Pi`.

On the other hand, by writing:

```
DiscreteLimit[n Sin[2 Pi E n!], n -> Infinity]
```

we get the correct result:

> $2 \pi$

A last chance that could sometimes be comfortable is the following:

```
Limit[(1 - Cos[x])/x^2, x -> 0]
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]
NLimit[(1 - Cos[x])/x^2, x -> 0, WorkingPrecision -> 15]
```

through which we obtain:

> $\frac{1}{2}$
>
> 0.500000

I hope it is useful.

Comment: `Limit[n Sin[2 Pi E n!], n -> Infinity]` doesn't exist, so `Indeterminate` is no mistake

Comment: To reinforce comment by @Coolwater, look at `LogLinearPlot[n Sin[2 Pi E n!], {n, 1, 100}, WorkingPrecision -> 200, 
 PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: The limit exist if $n\in\mathbb N$, and it doesn't if $n\in\mathbb R$ (cf. the code by Bob Hanlon vs. `Show[DiscretePlot[n Sin[2 Pi E n!], {n, 1, 30}, WorkingPrecision -> 100], Plot[2 Pi, {n, 1, 30}]]`). The output my MMA is correct: `Indeterminate` in the real case, `2 Pi` in the discrete case.